# Are there downloadable samples of Geoprocessing tools that can be published as Geoprocessing Service tasks?

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I am looking for examples of Geoprocessing Services which contain a tool/script for download.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Server are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to expand on PolyGeo's answer...I've personally put a lot of model/script tools up on arcgis.com that have the purpose of being used as a Geoprocessing Service.

In no particular order, heres all the ones I can think of:

- [Tutorials from the ArcGIS Server help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_the_geoprocessing_service_examples/015400000555000000/). And the [download of data, models and scripts](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6987d0a0daa14fe9861bae93e4808845) which go with those tutorials.
- Esri UC/DevSummit Presentations on Creating Geoprocessing Services. We always include the tools and usually some sample data. [UC 2012](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fd8e1bcee27b41df918519beb79fa1b3), [UC 2013](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=acd527d6de26455a9049aa16df758ed8)
- If you're familiar with the Esri SampleServers, every Geoprocessing Service has been added as a GPK to this [group on ArcGIS.com](http://bit.ly/1f9sxYt). Make sure to check the box "show Desktop content" on the left side to see the items.
- The [education gallery](http://www.arcgis.com/home/group.html?owner=ArcGISTeamAnalysis&title=ArcGIS%20Analysis%20team%20-%20Education%20gallery) is a list of presentations. While not specific to geoprocessing services, you might find something interesting and helpful.
- [Much older presentations](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/geoprocessing/10.0/presentations) (UC/Dev Summit 2009-2011). There are a few GP Service specific ones in there you can find.
- This isn't "data to download", but the [videos which match the presentations from 2012/2013 can be found here](http://video.esri.com/search/creating-geoprocessing-service).
- Last, but not least, the GP team has their own Server for GP Service demos. You can [browse it here](http://gpdemos.esri.com/). This server is a bit of a work in progress and will be updated/modified as time goes on. It's real purpose is to show a workflow in its entirety: tool on desktop, tool as service, web app to consume.

Comment: It is really helpful post- all in one place!!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you take **[A quick tour of the geoprocessing service examples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_the_geoprocessing_service_examples/015400000555000000/)** in the ArcGIS for Server 10.1 online help.